# Spring security login not working remotely

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have set up a very simple login (with jdbc authentication - copy/paste from reference + customization to my endpoints) what is *working perfectly when running locally (accessing localhost)* but as soon as I am deploying (spring boot) and try **to access the server remotely it is not working at all**.

I could not catch any exception. But there must be something because it is getting to the `/error` handler. I have custom error page what would print the stacktrace but there is nothing.

when increased debug details (application.property added `logging.level.org.springframework.security: DEBUG`) I see that there was some anonymousUser recognized (after the `/login` immediately). But no error at all.

The database is fully accessible because there are some other part of the app what is accessible without authentication and working well.

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    http
        .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession( true )
        .clearAuthentication( true )
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers( "/tags/**" ).authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
  }

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier( "localDataSource" )
  private DataSource localDataSource;

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
        .dataSource( localDataSource )
    ;
  }
```

Spring boot version : 2.1.0.RELEASE
java 8

**EDIT:**

It turned out there is nothing wrong with the settings. I have discovered that it is working in other browser or in the same browser the next day. It helped me to discover that it was more related to session cache.

Once I experienced this I wen to the developer console (firefox) and cleared all session data. And it started working properly.

Comment: Show your log file containing the login in request.

Comment: can you show your `application.properties` ?